# PowerShell: Why does truth contain lies?

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\> $true -contains "Lies"
True
```

...?

`help about_operators` says

> comparison operators include the containment operators (in, -notin,
>   -contains, -notcontains), which determine whether a test value appears in a reference set.

`$true` is not a collection, how can it be a "reference set" and contain ... anything at all? It doesn't contain falsey things.

---

Similarly `$null -in $null` is True

Comment: Good question, but please avoid the ill-defined term "container [type]"; the umbrella term that PowerShell generally uses for multiple items addressed as a single entity is _collections_ (even though the unusual term _reference set_ is used in _this_ instance, it appears only _once_ in all `about_*` topics (`Get-Help -Category HelpFile | ? { Get-Help -Full $_.Name | Select-String -Quiet '\breference\s+set\b' }`)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$true` get converted to a collection of 1 element, so it's equivalent to:

```
# ~> @($true) -contains "Lies"
True
```

So each element in the collection gets compared to "Lies" :

```
# ~> $true -eq "Lies"
True
```

So the real question is, why does the above expression evaluate to true. What's happening is that it is converting the right hand side of the oepration to match the type of  the left hand side:

```
# ~> $true -eq [Bool]"Lies"
True
```

because:

```
# ~> [Bool]"Lies"
True
```

so if you swap the operation:

```
# ~> "Lies" -eq $true
False
```

because:

```
# ~> [String]$true
True
```

Similarly, `$null -in $null` is the same as `$null -in @($null)` and `$null -eq $null` is true.

Comment: "*$true get converted to a container of 1 element*" - ohhh that magic conversion popping up again. Great answer, thanks.

Comment: (I can now add `$true[0] -contains "True"[-1]` to my "obfuscated powershell" plans :P )