# Testing a collection for null

Tags: powershell

Why is it, when I test a collection for `null` and put the collection as the first parameter, it returns the collection if it's not `null`, and if it is `null` it returns `null`.

I realised that if I cast it to `[bool]`, it fixes the problem. But I thought the `-eq` would output a `Bool` value without the need for a cast?

```
$objectArray = @('a','b','c','d')

$objectArray -ne $null
<#
a
b
c
d
#>

[bool]($objectArray -ne $null)
#True

$objectArray -eq $null
#Nothing is outputted

[bool]($objectArray -eq $null)
#False

$null -ne $objectArray
#True

$null -eq $objectArray
#False
```

When I test a normal string, I get the expected results as seen below:

```
$object = 'a'

$object -ne $null
#True

$object -eq $null
#False

$null -ne $object
#True

$null -eq $object
#False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't "return the collection if it's not null", it returns *the items in the collection which are not null*". Any which were null would be filtered out (but there weren't any, so it doesn't change). Binary operators applied to arrays act as filters.

```
'a','b','c' -eq 'b'       #output is 'b'

1,2,3,4,5 -lt 3           #output is 1,2

1,2,$null,4,5 -ne $null   # output is 1,2,4,5

1,2,$null,4,5 -eq $null   # output is $null
```

Your code:

```
[bool]($objectArray -ne $null)
#True
#filters the array, returns some values
#arrays with some things in them cast to true

$objectArray -eq $null
#Nothing is outputted
# nothing in the array was null, no output.

[bool]($objectArray -eq $null)
#False
# filters the array, empty arrays cast to false
```

> When the input to an operator is a scalar value, comparison operators
>       return a Boolean value. When the input is a collection of values, the 
>       comparison operators return any matching values. If there are no matches
>       in a collection, comparison operators do not return anything.
>
> The exceptions are the containment operators (-Contains, -NotContains),
>       the In operators (-In, -NotIn), and the type operators (-Is, -IsNot),
>       which always return a Boolean value.

- [get-help about_comparison_operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (which is a lot more complete and accurate and helpful, really)

Comment: why does it change if $null is before the array when using -eq etc?

Comment: With one thing on the left, the operator tests the one thing on the right against it, and outputs $true or $false. With an array on the left, the operator tests against the things in the array, and filters selecting the ones that were $true, the output is the matching items. *And*, during any comparison, the thing on the right is cast to the type of the thing on the left, so `1 -eq "1.0"` casts the string to a number and is $true, but `"1.0" -eq 1` casts the number to a string, and is $false. *Except*, `$null` is different and special and implicit casting does not happen, only $null -eq $null.

Comment: So there's comparison with implicit casting, if the types are different then it matters which side things are on. Then there's $null which is a special case. Then there's "testing against an array on the left" as a convenience syntax sitting on top of that.

Comment: (Except if the operator you use is `-in` or `-contains`, and they [implicitly promote the thing on the left into an array, if it is not already one, and always return booleans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002509/powershell-why-does-truth-contain-lies) from a question I asked a few months ago].

Answer (score 0):

To complement [TessellatingHeckler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40392496/45375):

**To *force* evaluation of operators that also accept *collections* as the LHS to evaluate in a *scalar* context - and therefore return a `[bool]` instance rather than a filtered collection - *place the scalar on the LHS*:**

```
# ALWAYS returns a [bool], because the LHS (left-hand side) is a SCALAR:
$null -eq $someVariableThatMayBeAscalarOrAnArray
```

If you **make a habit out of this whenever you mean to perform scalar comparison to get a *Boolean* result,** you won't be surprised if the other operand happens to be a collection.
Placing the (literal) scalar on the LHS may look odd at first, but understanding the underlying issue will help with the transition.