# PowerShell collection operators -in and -contain not acting as expected

Tags: powershell, contains, operator-keyword

I have a calculated PowerShell variable that may be set to $True (Boolean), or 'True' (String), or $False (Boolean), or 'False' (String), and I want to test if it's "True" (Boolean or string).

While I can easily frame the successfully test as below:

```
$MyVar = $false
If (($MyVar -eq $True) -or ($MyVar -eq 'True')) {1} Else {0}
```

0

If I change this to the more succinct format below, I get the unexpected result:

`If ($MyVar -in @($True,'True')) {1} Else {0}`
1

Can anyone explain why the collection operators -in and -contains behave this way?
I've observed this behavior with PowerShell 5.1 and PWSH 7.4.1

I've tried numerous variations of this, and the same unexpected behavior is observed.

`If ('False' -in @($true)) {1} else {0}`
1

`If (@($true) -contains 'False') {1} else {0}`
1

This stackoverflow article: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002509/powershell-why-does-truth-contain-lies](https://stackoverflow.com)
says: 'What's happening is that it is converting the right hand side of the operation to match the type of the left hand side';e.g.
`$true -eq "Lies" ~> $true -eq [Bool]"Lies"`
True

But that doesn't seem to be happening when I reverse the comparison elements here:

`If ('False' -in @($true)) {1} else {0}`
1

Comment: [bool]'False' is $true.

Comment: Use `[bool]::Parse($var)` to avoid unexpected results. This way will be reliable for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

To avoid the pitfall described in the next section, use:

```bash
if ("$MyVar" -eq 'True') { 1 } Else { 0 }
```

That is, *stringify* your variable using an [expandable (interpolating), double-quoted string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) and perform *string* comparison:

- If `$MyVar` is a `[bool]` instance, it stringifies to either `'True'` or `'False'` *irrespective of the current culture*
- If `$MyVar` already *is* a string, the enclosure in `"..."` is in effect a no-op.

Note that the [`-eq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq) operator is case-*insensitive* by default; if you want to case-exact matching, use its case-sensitive variant, `-ceq`.

---

##### Type coercion in `-in` / `-contains` operations:

`'False' -in @($true)` is equivalent to `@($true) -contains 'False'`.

That is, the two operators involved, [`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) and [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains), are equivalent and differ only in which operand is the scalar vs. the collection to test containment in.

In *both* cases, it is the elements of the *collection* operand that effectively act as the *LHS* of the implied `-eq` comparison performed for *each collection element* against the scalar operand.

Therefore, both of the above are the *effective* equivalent of:

```bash
@($true).Where({ $_ -eq 'False' }, 'First').Count -eq 1
```

Given that it is generally<sup>[1]</sup> the *LHS* of operations that drives *implicit type coercions* in PowerShell, **with `-in` and `-contains` it is therefore *each collection element* that drives type coercions**.

With a `[bool]` instance as the LHS, as in the case at hand, the RHS is coerced to that type based on the rules described in [about_Booleans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Booleans).
These rules notably include considering *any nonempty string* to be `$true`, *irrespective of the string's content*.

Thus, `$true -eq 'False'` is - perhaps surprisingly - `$true`, given that `'False'` is a *nonempty string*.

---

<sup>[1] There are exceptions: `-` and `/` invariably interpret coerce *both* operands to *numbers*; e.g., `'10' - '2'` yields `[int] 8`. The reason is that with these specific operators interpretation *as numbers* is the only sensible interpretation - unlike with polymorphic operators such as `+` and `*`.</sup>